# How to add a comma or locale specific thousands separator to amounts?

Tags: recurly

Problem:
On the form in recurly.js, the amounts are not shown with any separator (e.g. 1,000 or 1.000).  In the [documentation](https://recurly.com/developers/reference/recurly-js), I can't find any reference.  The only thing they have is to review their code or turn to SO to find an answer, because sometimes they look here.

I don't see anything similar in already asked questions.  Is there a way to do this?